# How does java Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...) search for executables on windows?

Tags: java, windows, cmd

I'm trying to do a proof of concept exploit to show how changing the path variable can replace standard programs for malicious ends. I put a dummy program called "cmd.exe" in a directory "C:\path\to\fake_exe\" and changed the path to have that at the front.

Below is the function I'm using to demonstrate, but it runs normally (i.e., it passes the arguments to the correct cmd.exe instead of my fake one). I even passed "cmd" to the function, and it opened my dummy program! So the path variable is definitely set to find my fake cmd.exe correctly, but the `exec(..)` function is finding the proper cmd.exe regardless.

How does the `exec(...)` function find executables? Where is this documented?

```
static void unsafeExec(String cmd) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String[] run = new String[3];
    run[0] = "cmd.exe";
    run[1] = "/C";
    run[2] = cmd;

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(run);
    BufferedReader stdIN = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader stdER = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
    p.waitFor();
    String s;
    while ((s = stdIN.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    while ((s = stdER.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.print(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: `exec` probably relies on WinAPI `CreateProcess` to search for "cmd.exe", which calls `SearchPath` using the base API's executable search path: `%__AppDir__%;%__CD__%;%SystemRoot%\System32;%SystemRoot%\System;%SystemRoot%;%Path%`. The `__AppDir__` dynamic variable is the directory of the current process executable, and `__CD__` is the current process working directory. The system can be configured to skip searching `__CD__`, which `CreateProcess` checks by calling `NeedCurrentDirectoryForExePath`. We assume that the application directory is secure and the working directory is not secure.

Comment: An exception to the application directory being secure is when users run portable apps and installers directly from their Downloads folder instead of first copying the executable to a secure location.

Comment: You are correct! I just downloaded the JRE source code and stepped through the whole execution path. It eventually gets to a ProcessBuilder, which definitely calls the Windows CreateProcess. Thanks!